# Execute Excel Macro, Then Import Into Access Table On Multiple Excel Files In A Folder

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, macros

I need to import multiple Excel spreadsheets into an Access table.  The spreadsheets currently look like this:

```
ID | Year | Sales | Commissions
-- | ---- | ----- | -----------
 1 | 2016 | 1,000 |  100
 2 | 2016 | 2,000 |  200
 3 | 2016 | 3,000 |  300
 4 | 2016 | 1,000 |  300
```

They need to look like this:

```
ID | Name | Year | Month | Sales | Commissions | Discount | Net Sales | %
-- | ---- | ---- | ----- | ----- | ----------- | -------- | --------- | -
 1 | John | 2016 |  2    | 1,000 |  100        |          |           |
 2 | Mary | 2016 |  2    | 2,000 |  200        |          |           |
 3 | Jake | 2016 |  2    | 3,000 |  300        |          |           |
 4 | Bob  | 2016 |  2    | 1,000 |  300        |          |           |
```

The last three columns will be blank.  Names ("John, Mary...") will use a lookup based on ID on another spreadsheet, but this can be done later in Access.  3 rows will have to be deleted at the top as well.  The month ("2") will be in the file path of the Excel file.  It will be the only number in the file name.  I.e., "2" for February.  All the spreadsheets will be in the same folder.  Each Excel workbook will have a spreadsheet titles "DataSheet".  This is the spreadsheet that will be imported from each workbook.

Can I write a script in Access to do all of this?

So far I've got this for the Excel macro:

```
  Sub Macro2()
    Rows("1:3").Select
    Range("A3").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Name"
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Month"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Discount"
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Net Sales"
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " %"
    Range("G2").Select
End Sub
```

[Here's something](http://www.accessmvp.com/kdsnell/EXCEL_Import.htm) like this would import multiple files:

```
    Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
    blnHasFieldNames = False
    strTable = "tablename"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
          strPathFile = strPath & strFile
          DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
          strFile = Dir()
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some simple vlookups to me.  Once you get the excel stuff straightened out, and you are ready to import multiple files into a table, just run a script like this.

```
Sub ImportAllFilesIntoOneTable

        Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
        Dim strTable As String
        Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

        ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
        ' has field names
        blnHasFieldNames = False

        ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
        ' contains the EXCEL files
        strPath = "C:\Documents\"

        ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
        ' the data are to be imported
        strTable = "tablename"

        strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
              strPathFile = strPath & strFile
              DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                    strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

        ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
        ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
        '       Kill strPathFile

              strFile = Dir()
        Loop

End Sub
```